# How can you write this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have two tables.
The structure of tables is as follows.

### TRAILERS_INVENTORY

- TRAILER_TYPE VARCHAR2(100)
- TRAILER_LENGTH INT
- TRAILER_WIDTH INT
- YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE INT

### NEW_INVENTORY

- NEW_INVENTORY_TYPE_ID INT,
- TRAILER_TYPE VARCHAR2(100),
- TRAILER_LENGTH INT,
- TRAILER_WIDTH INT,
- YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE INT

I want to list all of the trailers that do not have a NEW_INVENTORY_TYPE_ID. I am using Oracle 9.2.

One approach is to use a set operation along the lines of

```
SELECT TRAILER_TYPE
 FROM TRAILERS_INVENTORY 
WHERE TRAILER_TYPE NOT IN (SELECT TRAILER_TYPE, 
                                  TRAILER_LENGTH, 
                                  TRAILER_WIDTH, 
                                  YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE 
                             FROM TRAILERS_INVENTORY 
                           INTERSECT 
                           SELECT TRAILER_TYPE, 
                                  TRAILER_LENGTH, 
                                  TRAILER_WIDTH, 
                                  YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE 
                             FROM NEW_INVENTORY);
```

**IS THERE ANOTHER APPROACH AVAILABLE?**

Comment: Do you mean "I want to list all of the trailers that are in TRAILERS_INVENTORY but not in NEW_INVENTORY?"

Comment: Is the TRAILER_TYPE a foreign key? Do you want all rows from TRAOLERS_INVERTORY that is not referenced by any NEW_INVENTORY.TRAILER_TYPE?

Comment: @Joni, It is not a foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a couple of options

```
SELECT
    TRAILER_TYPE
FROM
    TRAILERS_INVENTORY
WHERE
    TRAILER_TYPE NOT IN (SELECT TRAILER_TYPE FROM NEW_INVENTORY)
```

Or:

```
SELECT
    TRAILER_TYPE
FROM
    TRAILERS_INVENTORY
LEFT JOIN
    NEW_INVENTORY
    ON (NEW_INVENTORY.TRAILER_TYPE = TRAILERS_INVENTORY.TRAILER_TYPE)
WHERE
    NEW_INVENTORY.NEW_INVENTORY_TYPE_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Why is a LEFT JOIN required? Will a regular JOIN not work in this case?

Comment: @Danra: With a normal join you only get the rows from `TRAILERS_INVENTORY` with a matching `NEW_INVENTORY` row. If that's not available than it won't be returned. Since we don't know if there's a 1-to-1 relation between `NEW_INVENTORY` and `TRAILERS_INVENTORY` we cannot use a normal join.

Answer (score 1):

So, the question is how can you perform this query without using a "set" operation?

Can I ask why you wouldn't use a set?

Everything you do in SQL is based on sets, but if you want a slower, less elegant solution you can reduce your set size to 1 and loop through `TRAILERS_INVENTORY` using PL/SQL.

```
declare
    v_exists varchar2(1 char);
begin
    for item in (select distinct trailer_type from trailers_inventory) loop
        begin
            select 'Y' into v_exists from new_inventory
            where trailer_type = item.trailer_type;
        exception
            when no_data_found then
                v_exists := null;
        end;
        if v_exists is null then
            dbms_output.put_line(item.trailer_type || ' not in ' || ' NEW_INVENTORY');
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Eek! That's why set operations are the way to go.

:)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT 
TRAILER_TYPE, 
TRAILER_LENGTH, 
TRAILER_WIDTH, 
YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE 
FROM TRAILERS_INVENTORY 
MINUS
SELECT 
TRAILER_TYPE, 
TRAILER_LENGTH, 
TRAILER_WIDTH, 
YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE 
FROM NEW_INVENTORY
```

Comment: That's still using the SET operations.

Comment: Oh yes, I did not read the part about set operations. Anyway, I think this is the way to go in general.